# Read unreadable error message in PhpStorm with darcula theme

Tags: terminal, phpstorm

I have a readability problem in the error messages (symfony) that the PhpStorm terminal sends me. Red background with **grey** text. Do you have a solution for a better legibility?

I'm use :

- Windows OS
- PhpStorm
- Darcula theme

[image: error_terminal]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a known issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-182750 & it's not yet addressed. Please vote for and comment it to receive notifications about it's progress.

Answer (score 13):

It's now 2018 but I still had this issue. So for people that might visit this topic the solution that worked for me:

Go to prefereces

- Mac: command + ,
- Linux: ctrl + alt + s

Go to: Editor -> Color Scheme -> Console Colors

Open the list with ANSI Colors

Look for the colors you want to change:

- Red (this is the background color of the error message)
- Gray (the foreground color of the error messages)

I changed the color's to

- Red: #DF0B08
- Gray: #CCCCCC

But that might depend on what you prefer and how it looks on the screen you are using.

Comment: Very nice alternative solution! :-)

Comment: Good colors chosen!